# How to set image's header of NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, image, macos, nstableview

I have a NSTableView and I want to load and display an NSImage in the headers of my columns.
There are no options for doing that with interface builder directly.
How I can do this with subclassing ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create class which derive from : NSTableColumn
and rewrite the -(id)headerCell selector.

Example :

```
@interface ImageTableColumn : NSTableColumn
{
    NSString *imageName;
}
@end

@implementation ImageTableColumn

- (id)headerCell
{
    NSCell *cell = [super headerCell];
    NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:imageName];
    image.size = NSMakeSize(32, 32);
    [cell setImage:image];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

In interface builder set Custom class of the column which must display the image.

[image: Select the concerned column]
[image: Affect your subclass in Custom Class field]

In order to have one "generic" class, you can use user defined runtime attributes for setting the image (imageName ref to the NSString* imageName field).

[image]